# Combine multiple jQuery Deferred objects into a new Deferred object

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

here's the code:
http://jsbin.com/lizami/edit?js,console

Paste the code here as well:

```
var aaa = $.Deferred();

var bbb = function(data){

    console.log(data);

    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    setTimeout(function(){
        dfd.resolve("bbb is done");
    }, 1000);
    return dfd.promise();
};

var ccc = function(data){
    console.log(data);

    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    setTimeout(function(){
        dfd.resolve("ccc is done");
    }, 1000);
    return dfd.promise();
};

var ddd = function(data){
    console.log(data);

    return data;
};



aaa.then([bbb,ccc]).then(ddd);
aaa.resolve("aaa is done");
```

What I want is to start two new deferred: `bbb` and `ccc` when `aaa` is resolved. And when both `bbb` and `ccc` are resolved. call `ddd` with the resolved data of `bbb` and `ccc`.

Is it possible? The jsbin doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In jQuery, you can use `$.when()` to combine multiple promises into one.

```
aaa.then(function() {
    return $.when(bbb(), ccc());
}).then(ddd);
```

This will wait for `aaa` to resolve, then it will run both `bbb()` and `ccc()` and when they both resolve, it will then call `ddd()`.

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/2f7btsq7/

Answer (score 2):

Rather old question but it took me some time to find an answer for a dynamic number of deffereds/promises that are to be combined:

```
const promises = [];
promises.push($.Deferred());
...
promises.push($.Deferred());
// execute $.when using Function.apply to pass the array of promises as arg
$.when.apply(null, promises).done(function() {
  // executed after all promises are "done"
});
```

In the context of the OP's question:

```
aaa.then(function() { return $.when.apply(null, [bbb(), ccc()] }).done(ddd));
```