# Rails Actioncable message coming before document ready

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, websocket, actioncable

I am trying to use ActionCable and websockets to implement a page where the server is doing some stuff via a Sidekiq job and that is sending messages back to the user's browser to cause the page to be updated. Should be simple, right?

I'm doing the first most basic thing, which is essentially sending a message in the controller, and the browser's Javascript should process it. Well, it does, but it does so *well* before the page is loaded/ready. And I'm trying to figure out why.

Here's the controller simplified:

```ruby
def create
  some stuff
  render
  ActionCable.server.broadcast "opml_items_channel:#{current_user.id}",
            { message: "Current Status: Found #{@opml_items.length} items" }
end
```

And here's the Javascript for the channel:

```javascript
App.opmlitems = App.cable.subscriptions.create("OpmlItemsChannel", {
  connected: function() {
    //console.log("connected");
  },

  disconnected: function() {
    //console.log("disconnected");
  },

  received: function(data) {
    //console.log("recieved");
    console.log(data['message']);
    // wait for document ready otherwise the message comes before the
    // page is rendered
    $( document ).ready(function() {
      console.log("doing the thing")
      console.log(document.querySelector('#status-p'));
      if ( document.querySelector('#status-p') != null ) {
        document.querySelector('#status-p').innerText = data['message'];
      }
    });
  }
});
```

This totally works in that the console logs *"doing the thing"*, but it does this even before the page is fully loaded by the browser, despite the `document.ready`. Looking at the browser console I see:

```
Current Status: Found 11 items
doing the thing
null
Navigated to http://localhost:3000/opml_items
```

The `null` is because `#status-p` doesn't exist yet at the time the `received` function is called.

In the rails log I see:

```
Started POST "/opml_items" for 127.0.0.1 at 2020-04-06 01:14:33 +0000
Processing by OpmlItemsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"7UQye0uFoThYZvoP8cxW/Wbz+QEi6IR5TXYoJFQeD1cXl5h6SZRYDpAyRIX7EYoQu6mGO/r76XgGZRap2le1hQ==", "upload"=>{"opml_file"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007f0bfeeac3b8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20200406-358-1ekfo8l.opml>, @original_filename="too-many.opml", @content_type="text/x-opml+xml", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"upload[opml_file]\"; filename=\"too-many.opml\"\r\nContent-Type: text/x-opml+xml\r\n">}, "commit"=>"Import OPML"}
blah blah standard rails stuff
[ActionCable] Broadcasting to opml_items_channel:1: {:message=>"Current Status: Found 11 items"}
Completed 200 OK in 713ms (Views: 612.4ms | ActiveRecord: 28.8ms | Elasticsearch: 0.0ms)
```

So, this is a long way around of asking -- how can I make ActionCable messages come fully after the page is rendered? You can see my `render` in there which makes the order (*in the log*) indicate that the ActionCable message comes at the very end. However, as far as the browser is concerned, it still doesn't seem to be honoring the `ready`.

WDYT?

Comment: You're thinking about it wrong. Doing async calls before the document is actually a good thing as it let's you make it really snappy. If you need an event handler to be called when both the message is loaded and when the DOM is fully loaded use a promise. https://stackoverflow.com/q/33060171/544825

Comment: I can see the value in messages coming before the document is loaded. In this particular case, though, I need most of the document to be present so that the things happening on the back end can start to actually happen before updating the dom. Will check out promises!